# Take data from a field from exsisting node and make that the default value of a field in different content type

Tags: drupal, cck

I don't know if I'm on the right track but I'm trying to let users of my web site create there own versions of pages on my web site.
Basically I'd like to make our documentation used as a starting point where they just add details and make a new page for themselves in the process.
I have a 'book' content type that I have changed with CCK and a 'client edits' content type that uses a nodereferencefromURL widget to link itself to the book node.

So simple version of what I'm saying is I have a link on my book pages that creates a node using client edits content type. I would like to put some fields on the client edits content type that take the values of some of the fields from the book page it is linked from.

I'm sure I'm missing something as I would have thought someone would have tried this before but I can't even find a hint on how to go about this.

All I really need is a point in the right direction if my current thinking is wrong.
Current thinking is that I use a php script to get the default value for a field on the new node add screen that drags the value for a field from the book I'm linking from.
I'm thinking this is the case because there is an option for default values for the field in cck manage fields that lets you put in a php value to return a default value for your field.

Am I on the right track or is there already a module or process that does what I'm talking about and I'm just too dumb to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using rules to save information from the user and the cloned node into hidden fields. 
One that saved the original node ID into a field when ever you create content of that type unless the url ends with Clone. This means that when you create the clone the original node ID is kept in the field.
That made it easy to use a views argument that took the node ID to make the clone appear along side the original when a user visits the original page.
The second rule trick was to compute a field that saved the "store name" from the profile of the user only when saving clone content. 
This meant that there was a hidden field on the clone that stored the info so I could then use another views argument to restrict the view to only people with the same store name in their profile.
I am no good with PHP but I managed to find a snippet (can't remember where) that returns the store name of the current logged in user as the argument.

`global $user;`

profile_load_profile($user);

return $user->profile_store_name;

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a little strange, are your client edits going to be a diff from the original node or just coppied data?

I would prehaps do it a more simple way, just have book nodes, and have different fields disaply depending on who edits it (enable the content_permissions module). That way you can use the [node clone](http://drupal.org/project/node_clone) module to create the users copy.

You will need to [make a module](http://drupal.org/node/508) to contain your custom php code.

Comment: I had brushed over node clone earlier in the week because I was more interested in coping fields rather than the whole node but I hadn't factored in permissions. I'll try that I see how it goes. Thank you.
yes they are going to be different to the original as our program seems to get used in a thousand different ways depending on the client so they need to personalize our documentation for themselves and their staff.

Comment: Also the user must not be able to change original doc so if cloned does that mean they won't have permission to edit the new one as well as the field will be the same I guess? I'll try.

Comment: Permissions can be set so that user groups can only edit their own instance of something rather than every instance so you should be ok.

Comment: This Answer is not quiet the way to go unfortunatly. Node clone is a good module and the permissions did work they way you pointed out so thanks for teaching me more about these before I point out why the fix didn't get me over the line.
The problem is when you clone a node there is no way to reference the clone back to the origonal document. I need to do this.

Comment: My main page of documentation is tabbed into differnt parts. 
1. A tab for the origonal document that my staff and I prepare for clients. This tab is viewed by my direct clients.
2. A tab for the clone of the origonal that my clients prepare for thier staff. This tab will be filtered based on the client easily enough but without some kind of node refernce between the origonal node id and the clone how do I filter it so the right clone and only the right clone get's called. hope this makes sense. This is why I originlly tried nodereference. Thanks again for the original answer.